# Flask + Selenium + Ubuntu + Apache

Tags: python, apache, selenium, ubuntu, flask

I'm breaking my head here trying to get the Selenium Driver/Chromedriver to work on a Flask project on Ubuntu server 20.04, Python3.8.
The application runs perfectly when on stand alone, and on Debug mode.
But when I run it behind the web server, Apache2 with the WSGI module, it does not work right.
the message I'm greeting is "Chromedriver quite unexpectedly".

Again Chromedriver works well, path is correct and when I run it on debub on the server or even standalone remotely it work really great.

I'm runing out of options here if anyone could help I woud really appreciate it.

This is how I'm opening Chromedriver on my code:

```py
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("enable-automation")
    options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver", options=options)
```

Looking at the log from Apache this is the message I'm getting

```html
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13f73144538f15c00b370eda6706),platform=Linux 4.15.0-66-generic x86_64)
```

Comment: `Apache` usually runs code as different user (often as user `www`) with different privilages, probably with different environment settings and with different `current working directory` - all for your security - because if someone find bug in Apache then it could access your account and get your password or steel other informations.

Comment: If I run the same application on debuger mode on the same folder /var/www/html it runs perfectly, the problem is when I run it on the onde web. Do you have any suggestions or hints how to solve if permission issue?

Comment: as I said - it may not be problem with code but how apache/system runs it. At start you can use `print()` or `logging` to see what values will get program when you run it with `Apache`. ie. check `os.getcwd()`, `os.getenv`, etc. Because `Apache` may run it with different privilages so you may need to use full pathes, change privilages for folders so user `www` could access all files/program which you need - command `chmod` in Linux.

Comment: I tried changing the permissions and all, seems your suggestion didn't work. Any other hints or suggestions?